# SQL join in the where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am currently having to use two different queries to get back the results that I'm looking for. I have tried combining the two queries together, but that ends with me getting a large amount of extra(duplicates) data that I do not need. Below I have the working query listed.

```
    SELECT p1.note as Itemcode,
           order.ID as OrderNo,
           piece1.ID As Piece1,  
           piece2.ID As Piece2,
           i1.count as Unit,
           unit.count as TotalUnits,
           i1.rack as RackNo,
           p1.EndDate as Piece1Finish,
           p2.EndDate as Piece2Finish,
           unit.group as BatchNo
    FROM   db.dbo.unit
           JOIN db.dbo.order on order.entry_ID = unit.entry_ID
           JOIN db.dbo.piece piece1 on piece1.ID_piece = unit.ID_piece_1
           JOIN db.dbo.piece piece2 on piece2.ID_piece = unit.ID_piece_3
           JOIN db.dbo.items i1 on i1.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
           JOIN db.dbo.items i2 on i2.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
           JOIN db.dbo.items i3 on i3.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
           JOIN db.dbo.items i4 on i4.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
           JOIN db.dbo.process p1 on p1.ID_process = i1.ID_process
           JOIN db.dbo.process p2 on p2.ID_process = i2.ID_process
           JOIN db.dbo.process p3 on p3.ID_process = i3.ID_process
           JOIN db.dbo.process p4 on p4.ID_process = i4.ID_process
     WHERE p1.note like '12A%'
           and p1.ID_pieceorder = '1'
           and p1.ID_job = '150'
           and p2.ID_pieceorder = '3'
           and p2.ID_job = '150'
           and i1.count = i2.count
           and i1.count = i3.count
           and i1.count = i4.count
           and i1.rack = i2.rack
           and p1.note = p2.note
           and i1.status = '1' 
           and i2.status = '1'
           and p3.ID_pieceorder = '0'
           and p4.ID_pieceorder = '2'
           and p3.ID_job = '153'
           and p4.ID_job = '151'
           and i3.status = '0'
           and i4.status = '0'
           and order.status <> '4'
  ORDER BY OrderNo
```

This query works fine. The second set of data I query to find adds the following information

```
SELECT ...(same as above)
FROM   ...(same as above plus the following) 
       JOIN db.dbo.items i5 on i5.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
       JOIN db.dbo.items i6 on i6.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
       JOIN db.dbo.process p5 on p5.ID_process = i5.ID_process
       JOIN db.dbo.process p6 on p6.ID_process = i6.ID_process
WHERE  p1.note like '12B%'
       and ... (same as above plus the following)...
       and p5.ID_pieceorder = '1'
       and p5.ID_job = '152'
       and p6.ID_pieceorder = '3'
       and p6.ID_job = '152'
       and i5.status = '1'
       and i6.status = '1' 
       and i1.count = i5.count
       and i1.count = i6.count
```

When I try to make a combined query, the table joins of `i5`, `i6`, `p5`, and `p6` produce a massive amount of duplicated results for `p1.note like '12A%'` due to it not needing the fields. Is there a method where I can initiate a join in the `WHERE` statement so that it will only use those two tables when `p1.note like '12B%'`? Something along the lines of

```
SELECT ....
FROM   ....
WHERE  (p1.note like '12A%'
        or 
        (p1.note like '12B%'
         and p5.ID_pieceorder = '1'
         and p5.ID_job = '152'
         and p6.ID_pieceorder = '3'
         and p6.ID_job = '152'
         and i5.status = '1'
         and i6.status = '1' 
         and i1.count = i5.count
         and i1.count = i6.count
         (JOIN db.dbo.items i5 on i5.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
       JOIN db.dbo.items i6 on i6.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit
       JOIN db.dbo.process p5 on p5.ID_process = i5.ID_process
       JOIN db.dbo.process p6 on p6.ID_process = i6.ID_process)))
```

I know that the syntax above will not work, but I am looking for a method similar to that.

**EDIT FOR TABLE STRUCTURE requested by DRapp
I'm going to fill out the results I get with ID_unit 782327

```
-db.dbo.items-
-ID_item-  -ID_process-  -count- -status- -rack-  -ID_unit-
 628335     782328         1       0        25      782327
 628336     782330         1       1        25      782327
 628337     782331         1       1        25      782327
 628338     782333         1       0        25      782327
 628339     782335         1       1        25      782327
 628340     782336         1       1        25      782327
 628341     782337         1       0        25      782327

 -db.dbo.process-
 -ID_process-  -ID_unit-  -ID_pieceorder- -ID_job-  -sequence-
  782328        782327         0             50          1
  782329        782327         1             5305        1
  782330        782327         1             150         1
  782331        782327         1             152         2
  782332        782327         2             5408        2
  782333        782327         2             151         1
  782334        782327         3             5308        3
  782335        782327         3             150         1
  782336        782327         3             152         2
  782337        782327         0             153         4

  -db.dbo.unit-
  -ID_unit- -status- -ID_piece_1- -ID_piece_2--ID_piece_3--ID_product-count
  782327      2         5305         5408         5308         50      1
```

db.dbo.items contains a unique key for each "item" that goes into a part, it contains the corresponding process code, the "count" field, the "status" of each "item", the rack for each "item", and the unit ID of each "ITEM".

db.dbo.process contains the unique key for each "process", the ID_unit, `ID_pieceorder`, `ID_job`,  and the `sequence`. Each unit starts with `ID_pieceorder` 0 which is establishing the product type, then `ID_piece` 1 for the first piece, etc..

db.dbo.unit contains the unique key for each "unit", the codes for all its pieces, the status of the unit, and `count` which is the number of units.

```
db.dbo.piece is a table with the master list of codes on it. 

-ID_Piece-  -Desc-
 5305       14black
 5408       14blue
 150        Cut
```

The point of needing 6 processes is as follows
p1 & i1: Making sure the Piece is Piece 1, is process 150, and that process 150 is complete

p2 & i2: Making sure the piece is piece 2, is process 150, and that process 150 is complete

p3 & i3: Making sure it the completion process, 153, is not completed.

p4 & i4: making sure the connector process, 152, isn't completed(hasn't connected the two pieces).

p5 & i5: some pieces require extra work done, this checks and makes sure that process, 152, is completed on piece 1.

P6 & i6: The same as p5 & i5 but for piece 2.

Comment: Try a UNION ALL query

Comment: The biggest problem you have here is your underlying database structure. When you don't normalize your data you end up joining to the same table over and over like this. If you have better table structure the queries are a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean by "normalize your data"?

Comment: @HLGEM I will give that a try and I'll let you know what I get back.

Comment: You have repeating columns in your unit table. id_piece_1, id_piece_2 etc. This is a serious pain to work with. And if you are not careful you end up making accidents like you did in your code here. Look at the joins to items. They all 4 have the exact same join predicate. My guess is that should be ID_Unit_1, ID_Unit_2 or something like that. Then you do it all over again with process. Let me guess....you are getting 8 rows for every value you want. That is because of the joins. Whenever you start thinking you need to add column_2, etc you need to spin that off to a new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want duplicates use a Union in between them, move you order by clause to the bottom of the second one. Make sure you select columns are in the same order in both statements.

```
select (your columns)
From  (tables and joins)
where (your where)
UNION
select (your columns)
From  (tables and joins)
where (your where)
order by
```

Answer (score 1):

Per chatroom clarification, I have come up with the the following for you to start with and minimally adjust as needed.

```
SELECT 
      u.id_unit,
      u.count as TotalUnits,
      u.group as BatchNo,

      p1.ID_PieceOrder as Piece1Order,
      p1Cut.ID_Process as Piece1CutProcessID,
      i1Cut.Count as Item1CutCount,
      i1Cut.Status as Item1CutStatus,
      p1Tamp.ID_PieceOrder as Piece1OrderTampered,
      p1Tamp.ID_Process as Piece1TamperedProcessID,
      i1Tamp.Count as Item1TamperedCount,
      i1Tamp.Status as Item1TamperedStatus,

      p2.ID_PieceOrder as Piece2Order,
      p2Cut.ID_Process as Piece2CutProcessID,
      i2Cut.Count as Item2CutCount,
      i2Cut.Status as Item2CutStatus,
      p2Tamp.ID_PieceOrder as Piece2OrderTampered,
      p2Tamp.ID_Process as Piece2TamperedProcessID,
      i2Tamp.Count as Item2TamperedCount,
      i2Tamp.Status as Item2TamperedStatus,

      pSpacer.ID_PieceOrder as SpacerPieceOrder,
      iSpacer.Count as SpacerCount,
      iSpacer.Status as SpacerStatus,

      pSealed.ID_PieceOrder as SealedPieceOrder,
      iSealed.Count as SealedCount,
      iSealed.Status as SealedStatus
   FROM
      db.dbo.unit u

         JOIN Process p1
            ON u.ID_Unit = p1.ID_Unit
            AND u.ID_Piece_1 = p1.ID_Job
            JOIN Process p1Cut   -- ALL PIECES MUST BE CUT first
               ON p1.ID_Unit = p1Cut.ID_Unit
               AND p1.ID_PieceOrder = p1Cut.ID_PieceOrder
               AND p1Cut.ID_Job = 150
               JOIN Items i1Cut
                  ON p1Cut.id_process = i1Cut.id_process
               LEFT JOIN Process p1Tamp   -- NOT ALL PIECES MUST BE TEMPERED
                  ON p1Cut.ID_Unit = p1Tamp.ID_Unit
                  AND p1Cut.ID_PieceOrder = p1Tamp.ID_PieceOrder
                  AND p1Tamp.ID_Job = 152
                  LEFT JOIN Items i1Tamp
                     ON p1Tamp.id_process = i1Tamp.id_process


         JOIN Process p2
            ON u.ID_Unit = p2.ID_Unit
            AND u.ID_Piece_3 = p2.ID_Job
            JOIN Process p2Cut   -- ALL PIECES MUST BE CUT first
               ON p2.ID_Unit = p2Cut.ID_Unit
               AND p2.ID_PieceOrder = p2Cut.ID_PieceOrder
               AND p2Cut.ID_Job = 150
               JOIN Items i2Cut
                  ON p2Cut.id_process = i2Cut.id_process
               LEFT JOIN Process p2Tamp   -- NOT ALL PIECES MUST BE TEMPERED
                  ON p2Cut.ID_Unit = p2Tamp.ID_Unit
                  AND p2Cut.ID_PieceOrder = p2Tamp.ID_PieceOrder
                  AND p2Tamp.ID_Job = 152
                  LEFT JOIN Items i2Tamp
                     ON p2Tamp.id_process = i2Tamp.id_process

         LEFT JOIN Process PSpacer
            ON u.ID_Unit = PSpacer.ID_Unit
            AND u.ID_Job = 151
            LEFT JOIN Items ISpacer
               ON PSpacer.ID_Process = ISpacer.ID_Process

         LEFT JOIN Process PSealed
            ON u.ID_Unit = PSealed.ID_Unit
            AND u.ID_Job = 153
            LEFT JOIN Items ISealed
               ON PSealed.ID_Process = ISealed.ID_Process

   WHERE
      u.ID_Unit IN (782327, 782328, 782329 )
```

-- just a sample of 3 unit IDs to test concept of the revised query structure

I started at the unit table.  From that, I am taking each piece down its respective path... First to get the piece, then from the piece, its CUT which will always be required.  From the CUT to its ITEM status record which will always exist.  From the CUT, I am then looking for a TAMPERED status for the same piece order.  Since not all glass needs to be tampered, I have this as a LEFT-JOIN.  I then LEFT-JOIN to the tampered's item record by the process id.

I do the same for the SECOND piece.

Then, a LEFT-JOIN to see IF there is a spacing required (can change to JOIN if spacer is ALWAYS required)

Finally, a LEFT-JOIN on the job completed entry.  Again, don't know if all the entries are pre-filled in up-front for ALL stages of the process vs not.

Notice my alias name reference from P1 for the process for piece 1, then the p1Cut to i1Cut, to p1Tamp to i1Tamp.  So now, instead of generic p1-p6, I have context to the process or item.  Additionally, I just grabbed all the columns from the respective piece, cut, tampered, spacer and sealed steps with clear column names.  If you don't want something you can always remove it, but with this, you SHOULD never get any duplicates per a single UNIT.

I did not add the join to the order or piece tables respectively.  I don't know if piece is really needed unless you had other columns such as the P1.Name, but your table structure dump showed the description.

Since I did not add any other qualifiers, you should get the entire status of a single UNIT in one row.  I would adjust the WHERE clause to pick a range of a few units you can test and confirm the context.  THEN, adjust the where clause to look for your other criteria such as an item count = another or not, or piece within your '%a%' context or not.  However, I THINK this will get you well on your way.

Comment: I edited my original post to add table structures as well as explanations. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Xestius, sorry delay in response... did you try altering your WHERE clause per my above content explanation?  You are probably getting way too much because of the mismatched parenthesis parts.

Comment: I have attempted to run it with that setup, but it still gives the extra responses. The issue I am having is that as long as the p5, i5, p6, and i6 tables are joined it, it will cause the the `p1.note like '12A%'` to generate duplicates from each of those tables, or if I include the clauses for tables 5 & 6 not in parentheses none of my `p1.note like '12A%'` returns results because they do not meet the conditions.

Comment: @Xestius, Additionally, it MIGHT be failing if the order is only a single piece, of which, you would never have a piece 2, and thus not have your corresponding P5 and P6 entries?  Is that accurate too?

Comment: It is based on glass, specifically making insulated glass units. Some units, `'12A%'` are just two pieces of glass that are cut and then sealed together, while other units, `'12B%'`, are two pieces of glass that are cut and then tempered before being sealed together. This structure cannot be altered as it is used by our scanning software to track the glass. The software package was made in Italy, and the table names are in partial Italian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102487/discussion-between-xestius-and-drapp).

Comment: @Xestius, I have gone to the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 LEFT JOIN db.dbo.process p1 
        on p1.ID_process = i1.ID_process 
       and p1.note like '12A%'
       and p1.ID_pieceorder = '1'
       and p1.ID_job = '150'
       and p2.ID_pieceorder = '3'
       and p2.ID_job = '150'
       and i1.count = i2.count
       and i1.count = i3.count
       and i1.count = i4.count
       and i1.rack = i2.rack
       and p1.note = p2.note
       and i1.status = '1' 
       and i2.status = '1'
       and p3.ID_pieceorder = '0'
       and p4.ID_pieceorder = '2'
       and p3.ID_job = '153'
       and p4.ID_job = '151'
 LEFT JOIN db.dbo.items i5 
        on i5.ID_unit = unit.ID_unit 
       and p1.note like '12B%'
       and i5.status = '1'
```